# What does the values of covariance matrix tell us?

Tags: variance, covariance

Assume we have the following covariance matrix:

```
cov(x,y) = [var(x),    cov(x,y)  = [4 3
            cov(y,x),  cov(y) ]     3 4]
```

- What can we tell about the value of 3 ? (cov(x,y) = 3 ?)
- Can we infer that "one change of x, the y will change 3 times" ?
- Is there a meaning for the value 3 ? or we just used it's sign (positive or negative) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariance is a measure of linear dependence between $X$ and $Y$. In particular, you can infer that

$$\rho_{XY}=\frac{\mathbb{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\cdot \sigma_Y}=75\%$$

...there is a positive linear dependence of 75% between the two rv's

Comment: Thanks. If X have the values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], can we infer that wwill be the values of Y (from the covariance matrix) ?

Comment: Does the values of covariance tell us something ? or we just use them to calculate the correlation ?

Comment: @user3668129: you have not enough information to infer what will be the values Y. If $x_1=1$ , $y_1$ can be $1,100,-1000$...